# Preselect an option with rails f.select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-helper

I have a model question which has a column called category.

I have an array that lists all valid categories: Question.categories

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :category, options_for_select(Question.categories) %>
    #...
<% end %>
```

Say I have a variable called @currentlySelectedCategory.

Now how do I tell rails to preselect the option in the dropdown menu that matches @currentlySelectedCategory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :category, options_for_select(Question.categories, @currentlySelectedCategory) %>
    #...
<% end %>
```

But since you are using `form_for`, I would have thought that rails would select the question category.

Comment: Glad I could help, but you should read the doc for these kind of things ;)

Comment: I read the doc on select and associated methods and it was no help. I didn't realize that I should be looking at the doc for options_for_select instead :P